# Bounds of the chromatic number of the $\mathbb{R^n}$ graph with forbidden distance $1$

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics

We have the graph $G$ with vertex set $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}^*$) and any two vertices have an edge iff their euclidean distance ist equal to $1$. Now any two points with an edge must have different colors. The chromatic number $\chi$ of a graph is the smallest number of colors needed to color the graph. The following bounds with $\zeta = 1.239...$ are known:

$(\zeta + o(1))^n \leq \chi(G) \leq (3+o(1))^n$.

For any real funktion $f$, we have $f \in o(1) \Leftrightarrow |f(x)| \rightarrow 0$ for $x\to \infty$.

Can anyone explain this result to me? Or better, can anyone give an example for some $n \in \mathbb{N^*}$ so that we have natural numbers as bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you gave was proved by A. M. Raigorodskii (the lower bound) and Larman-Rodgers (the upper bound).

This formula means that the chromatic number $\chi(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of the above graph grows as an exponential function. In the literature one can find more precise estimates of the chromatic number for small $n\leq24$. For example,
$5\leq\chi(\mathbb{R}^2)\leq7$ and $5\leq\chi(\mathbb{R}^3)\leq18$.

A good survey can be found in A. Soyfer's book "The mathematical coloring book", chapter 10.